# isolate jquery keybind to a single focused element

Tags: jquery

How can I allow a form to be triggered with the user hits enter, but only if that field is in focus? This is what I have now, but pressing enter anywhere (obviously) triggers the form.

```
 jQuery(window).bind('keypress', function(e){
   if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
     jQuery("#goform").click();
     e.preventDefault();
   }
 });
```

Comment: Well, instead of `jQuery(window).bind`, try `jQuery('#elementID').bind`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the .bind on the element, not the entire window:

```
jQuery('#elementID').bind('keypress', function(e){
   if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
     jQuery("#goform").click();
     e.preventDefault();
   }
 });
```

If your field has id `elementID`. Offcourse you can approach the field by name, tagname or using any other [jQuery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

You chould use the selector to select the form element and assign the `keypress()` method to that object:

```
$('#idOfFormInputElement').keypress(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
    });
```

If the element is dynamically added, then `delegate()` could be used instead:

```
$('#idOfFormElement').delegate('#idOfFormInputElement', 'keypress',
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery('#{insert-your-form-field-id}')` instead of `jQuery(window)`

Answer (score 0):

The 'e' parameter that gets passed to the callback function will contain details of what element fired the 'keypress' event -

```
e.target.id
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/